# Surface integrals and inner product

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Need to prove that 
$$ \int_{\mathbb{S}_{+}^{n-1}} \frac{1}{\langle y,a\rangle ^n}dS(y) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!a_1\cdot...\cdot a_n}$$

Where $\mathbb{S}_{+}^{n-1} = \{x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1} ; \text{ where  } x_i \geq 0 \forall i=1,...,n\}$

The hint was to calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^n} e^{- \langle x,a\rangle} dx$

so I got that $\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^n} e^{- \langle x,a\rangle} dx = \frac{1}{a_1 \cdot ... \cdot a_n}$  but how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, for $x\in R^n_+$,
$$ x=ry, \text{where }\|x\|=r,y\in S_+^{n-1} $$
and
$$ dx=r^{n-1}dS(y)dr $$
where $dS$ is the area element of $S^{n-1}$. So
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^n} e^{- \langle x,a\rangle} dx\\
&=&\int_{(0,\infty)\times S_+^{n-1}} e^{- r\langle y,a\rangle} r^{n-1}dS(y)dr\\
&=&\int_{S_+^{n-1}}dS\int_0^\infty e^{- r\langle y,a\rangle} r^{n-1}dr\\
&=&\int_{S_+^{n-1}}\frac{(n-1)!}{\langle y,a\rangle^n}dS(y)\\
&=&(n-1)!\int_{S_+^{n-1}}\frac{1}{\langle y,a\rangle^n}dS(y)\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Can you please further explain transitions from lines 1 to 2 and 2 to 3?

Comment: For 1, $x=\|x\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}=ry$. For 2, see http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/volume_11.pdf. For 3, $R_+^n=(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}_+$.